# jQuery slider not visible after container div is toggled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, slider, toggle

I have a page which contains a jQuery-UI horizontal slider, created using a little function, inside a `div` which can be displayed / hidden by clicking on it's title, using `$.toggle()`.

Problem is, once the `div` is hidden, when it is expanded the slider is gone.

A simplified demo of the problem can be seen here: http://arr.gr/jquery-issue.html (file contains all relevant source code) - when clicking the "Advanced Options" title to hide and then show the `div`, the slider is no longer there.

Any suggestions on how to work around this?

Comment: Cannot duplicate with jQuery 1.4.2 /UI 1.8. Could this be an issue with the earlier releases? Which browser are you testing in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've downloaded your page.

Seems like problem is in `'blind'` option your pass to `.toggle()` function.

I've changed it to [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and everything worked as you expected.

UPD: `'blind'` is valid option for `.toggle()` with latest version of jquery ui (1.8.0) everything works fine.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Congratulations for your first answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this should be reported as a jQuery bug?

Comment: It seems to be fixed in 1.8.0 .